# It seems my submit button doesn't work. What could be the problem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

It shows no errors to aid in locating and fixing the problem. I've checked the database file and it's still empty.

The submit button `<div><%= f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-normal" %></div>`

The only thing that changes after submitting is the address. It changes from `http://localhost:3000/cars/new` to `http://localhost:3000/cars`

Everything else stays the same. How do i fix this?

Updated the question with the following;

**Log**

```
    Started GET "/cars/new" for ::1 at 2020-01-26 14:44:53 +0000
   (0.1ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
Processing by CarsController#new as HTML
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 12.1ms | Allocations: 1210)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 103)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
Completed 200 OK in 496ms (Views: 471.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms | Allocations: 15750)


Started POST "/cars" for ::1 at 2020-01-26 14:45:06 +0000
Processing by CarsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"Oom+xdVDc0PqSwLbLIEP0R8H6U38+v9ISVql4Fr/0WSxZGSrxzTHccsgghd1U30OugcUBAA1R4BtsB0YigAUtA==", "car"=>{"vehicle_type"=>"Sports", "car_type"=>"Private", "seat"=>"5", "colour_type"=>"Black", "transmission_type"=>"Automatic"}, "commit"=>"Create car"}
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 7.2ms | Allocations: 1144)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 103)
  Rendered shared/_message.html.erb (Duration: 0.1ms | Allocations: 17)
Completed 200 OK in 124ms (Views: 114.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 14757)
```

**Model** `app/models/car.rb`

```
class Car < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :vehicle_type, presence: true
  validates :car_type, presence: true
  validates :seat, presence: true
  validates :transmission_type, presence: true
  validates :engine, presence: true
end
```

**Controller** `app/controllers/cars_controller.rb`

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_car, except: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

  def index
    @cars = current_user.cars
  end

  def new
    @car = current_user.cars.build
  end

  def create
    @car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)
    if @car.save
      redirect_to listing_car_path(@car), notice: "Saved..."
    else
      render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def listing
  end

  def pricing
  end

  def description
  end

  def photo_upload
  end

  def features
  end

  def location
  end

  def update
    if @car.update(car_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Saved..."
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong..."
    end
    redirect_back(fallback_location: request.referer)
  end

  private
    def set_car
      @car = Car.find(params[:id])
    end

    def car_params
      params.require(:car).permit(:vehicle_type, :car_type, :seat, :transmission_type, :engine, :fuel_type, :colour_type, :window_type, :listing_name, :summary, :is_tv, :is_air, :is_internet, :is_sunroof, :is_bluetooth, :is_dvd, :is_gps, :is_usb, :is_audio, :is_airbags, :price, :active)
    end
end
```

Comment: have you checked your logs? my best guess, with the information available, is that your model fails validation and you aren't testing if it saved correctly in your `create` action.

Comment: Please show the form definition in your view and the responsible controller action. Also, please include the log entry showing the request to the server following the form submit.

Comment: Can you post the controller code for this resource, also it would help if you could post a copy of the params getting sent over.  Given the route changes it sounds like there is some kind of validation not working, or params that need to be whitelisted.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: From your logs it looks like you have validation errors and its rerendering new as a result. You might want to show those validation errors on your form to give some user feedback, but if you just want to get to the bottom of it then debug (eg, do `puts @car.errors.messages` before the save. From your params you appear to be missing `:engine` and `:user_id`, which your model requires.

Comment: I suggest you to look at this documentation: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#displaying-validation-errors-in-views

Comment: @David It's working now. turns out i did not include engine in my forms. Thanks to you and everyone here for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:**

**Solution is that you should either provide engine and user_id in params or you should remove presence true validation and add optional true case (for user association) from model.**

**Explanation:**

If your model says that it should validate presence of `engine` then how can you not provide engine param (in form). When you post the form without engine, what happens is that your model does not save it and as you have handled that case, it moves on. As it belongs to user, same goes for user ID. although you could make it optional too by adding optional: true both in schema and model (because a car can "be" without a user IRL but depends here in your use-case).

Going one step further, to exactly understand the issue yourself, use pry or byebug to see the params and happenings in runtime. Easier and faster way to verify the error is that put a bang in front of create method and it will show the error like: `if @car.save!`. One more thing: copy the car params and try to do this in rails console yourself manually with bang. It will give you the cause. These things will help you diagnose model save/create issues in rails.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Okay thanks. so i did not include engine in my form. I have done it now and it works. Thanks.

Comment: @Richard then I guess you should accept the answer as it precisely solved your issue :-)

Comment: Yes thanks but then I cannot even vote because I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: @Richard There is a tick mark below question voting option. That is the accept option and after accepting the answer you will have enough reputation to upvote my answer. Come on, you are a developer.

Comment: @Richard Thanks. As a newly-motivated contributor/helper, it helps a lot in motivation if someone accepts/votes-up cone's correct answers.

Answer (score 0):

From your log file

```
Started POST "/cars" for ::1 at 2020-01-26 14:45:06 +0000
```

Shows that the create action is being called on the cars controller
The parameters being passed in are

```
{"authenticity_token"=>"Oom+xdVDc0PqSwLbLIEP0R8H6U38+v9ISVql4Fr/0WSxZGSrxzTHccsgghd1U30OugcUBAA1R4BtsB0YigAUtA==", "car"=>{"vehicle_type"=>"Sports", "car_type"=>"Private", "seat"=>"5", "colour_type"=>"Black", "transmission_type"=>"Automatic"}, "commit"=>"Create car"}
```

The first method called on your create action is authenticate_user

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]
```

You can see that this happens

```
User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

According to your log the next thing that happens is

```
Rendering cars/new.html.erb within layouts/application
```

Which means that the else clause was hit `render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."`

```
@car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)
if @car.save
  redirect_to listing_car_path(@car), notice: "Saved..."
else
  render :new, notice: "Something went wrong..."
end
```

Therefore the car did not save so validation must have failed.
Your new car form should have an errors loop to display all the errors. If it did have this then your user (You) would know what went wrong

Something like this

```
  <% if car.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(car.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this car from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% car.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Should do the trick but it's standard in all rails generated forms so it should be there anyway